# Redis - Best data structure to store and then fetch large data

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I've recently implemented Redis into one of my Laravel projects. It's currently more of an technical exercise as opposed to production as I want to see what it's capable of.

What I've done is created a list of payment transactions. What I'm pushing to the list is the payload which I receive from a webhook every time a transaction is processed. The payload is essentially an object containing all the information to do with that particular transaction.

I've created a VueJS frontend that then displays all the data in a table and has pagination so it's show 10 rows at a time.

Initially this was working super quick but now that the list contains 30,000 rows which is about 11MB worth of data, the request is taking about 11seconds.

I think the issue here is that I'm using a list and am fetching all the rows from the list using LRANGE.

The reason I used a list was because it has the LPUSH command so that latest transactions go to the start of the list.

I decided to do a test where I got all the data from the list and outputted the value to a blank page and this took about the same time so it's not an issue with Vue, Axios, etc.

Firslty, is this read speed normal? I've always heard that Redis is blazing fast.

Secondly, is there a better way to increase read performance when using Redis?

Thirdly, am I using the wrong data type?

In time I need to be able to store 1m rows of data.

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed SI unit prefixes. `MB=megabyte` https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte whereas `mb=millibit` https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit

Comment: @MarkSetchell millibit doesn't exist. `[Bit (b)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)` is smallest, basic measure and you can't devide bit to smaller part(s).

Comment: @Tpojka That was what I was saying. The term `mb` was used in the original post, and I was saying that `m` is the SI prefix for `milli` and `b` is the SI unit of bits hence it would designate millibits - whether such a thing exists or not.

Comment: I've not a lot of experience with Redis, but you could check out existing packages and how they do it. Horizon for example seems to use a hashmap for the payloads and a sorted set for the keys with TTL. Check out their [RedisJobRepository](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/3.0/src/Repositories/RedisJobRepository.php). Even with a lot of elements (100k+), it feels quite fast (<1sec for sure).

Answer (score 0):

As I realized you get all 30,000 rows in any transaction update and then paginate it in frontend. In my opinion, the true strategy is getting lighter data packs in each request.
For example, use Laravel pagination in response to your request.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion:

- Firstly: As you know, Redis is blazing fast and Redis is really fast. Because Redis data always in memory, you say read 11MB data about use 11s, you can check your bandwidth
- Secondly: I'm sorry I don't know how to increase in this env.
- Thirdly: I think your choice ok.

So, you can check your bandwidth first(redis server).

Comment: you say: 'Initially this was working super quick but now that the list contains 30,000 rows which is about 11mb worth of data, the request is taking about 11seconds.'
And I want to know the 11s is read 30000 rows data or 10 rows data?

Comment: It was working quick when I had about 5000 rows of data but it's taking 11seconds now to pull all 30,000 rows from Redis. The 10 rows is just what is shown on the frontend in VueJS. The table has pagination so you can flick through all the data 10 rows at a time. I just didn't want people to think I'm trying to show 30k rows at once.

Comment: @Dally Do you use LRANGE command get 30000 rows data at once? If true, I think you can use LLEN get data count and get 10 rows data at once.